# In python, Is there any way to add two Byte arrays together like binary strings?

Tags: python, math, byte, bit

Is there any python packages for adding byte arrays together just like adding binary strings together.

For instance:

```
"0011" + "0101" = "0110"
```

but only with bytes.

I tried to convert the bytes to strings but its too much work for the computer. It would be easier to just add bytes together.

```
Bytearray1["10000011", "00000000"] 
+
Bytearray2["10000101", "00000000"]
=
Bytearray3["00000110", "00000001"]
```

Comment: How "0011" + "0101" becomes "0110" ?

Comment: Are you looking to concatenate byte arrays or to add binary values?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use bitwise operators. In your particular case you need [XOR](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) (bitwise exclusive or). In python XOR is denoted by ^.

Look at the example below:

```
a = int('0011', 2)
b = int('0101', 2)
c = a^b  
binary_rep = '{:04b}'.format(c)  # convert integer to binary format (contains 4 digits with leading zeros)
print(binary_rep)
```

The above code prints out '0110' to the screen.

You can also define your own function as follows:

```
def XOR(x, y, number_of_digits):
    a = int(x, 2)
    b = int(y, 2)
    c = a^b  
    format_str = '{:0%db}' % number_of_digits
    binary_rep = format_str.format(c) 
    return binary_rep
```